# How can I get an element from a Map if I haven't put it in it?

Tags: java, hashmap

Firstly I wanna say I am new to Map interface and started learning it yesterday,I found out this program

```
    public class maptest{


    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Integer> m = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    String argss[]={"i","came","i","left","i","saw"};
    for (String a : argss) {
        Integer freq = m.get(a);
        m.put(a, (freq == null) ? 1 : freq + 1);
     }

     System.out.println(m.size() + " distinct words:");
     System.out.println(m);

     }
     }
```

It's output is

> 4 distinct words:
>   {saw=1, left=1, came=1, i=3}

I wanna know I haven't put anything in Map yet I have just declared a String Array so How could i use

> m.get(a);

because There is nothing in my Map.I can only put something in Map via PUT method.

Comment: You get 1 for each unique word (because here freq is null, so your code puts value 1 when this happends). For "i" you get to 3, because you first put 1, then the next two times freq represents that previously put value to which you add 1 two more times, making it 3.

Comment: What is your question exactly? I don't understand what you don't manage to do.

Comment: @Joffrey I didn't get how output came I didn't get 2 lines where we are getting and putting values.

Comment: @Shivan How It is distinguishing between that word is distinct or not.

Comment: @TruePS maybe my answer will help on this. Feel free to ask if you don't understand something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Execution example

```
// first time that a is "i"
Integer freq = m.get(a); // returns null because "i" is not in the map
m.put(a, (freq == null) ? 1 : freq + 1); // associates 1 to the key "i"

// second time that a is "i"
Integer freq = m.get(a); // returns 1 because "i" is associated with 1
m.put(a, (freq == null) ? 1 : freq + 1); // associates freq+1 (=2) to the key "i"

// second time that a is "i"
Integer freq = m.get(a); // returns 2 because "i" is associated with 2
m.put(a, (freq == null) ? 1 : freq + 1); // associates freq+1 (=3) to the key "i"
```

### First step detail (get)

In the first step, `m.get(a)` simply returns `null` if no value is associated with `a`. In other words, if you have never encountered a word, you don't have any frequency yet, so you get `null` here:

```
Integer freq = m.get(a); // returns null if a is not associated
```

However, if the word was already encountered, we did put something non-null in the map (the frequency). Therefore, you get the frequency associated with the key.

**Note:** a `null` value could mean *"`null` is associated with `a`"* (not only *"`a` is not in the map"*). However, we never put `null` as a value for any key (see the next section).

### Second step detail (put)

This is using a [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/?%3a#Java)*: it puts 1 in the map if `freq` is `null`, or puts `freq+1` if `freq` is not null:

```
m.put(a, (freq == null) ? 1 : freq + 1);
```

The value that we put in the map is associated with the key that `a` currently holds, replacing any previous value. Later calls to `get()` will then return the new value that we just put.

---

(*) A construct like this: `condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false`

Comment: For HashMap, null values are possible. The way to be sure no value is associated with a key is `containsKey(key)` method returning false.

Comment: @anonymous That's true, but I didn't say that `null` value means no key. I just said the other implication is true. I don't think it matters for the OP's question. I believe the OP just wanted to know how it was possible to use `get()` while no key was added.

Comment: I interpreted your words `returns null if no value is associated with a` as meaning, the key does not exists in map. No value is associated with a key can only happen when key is not in the HashMap.

Comment: @Joffrey first of all sorry for disturbing you again.I understood that m.get(a) returns null first time and then 'i' is put in the map then it gets 'a' which is present in the map and freq becomes 2.So how m.size returns 4.

Comment: @anonymous I didn't say `if and only if`

Comment: @Joffrey I got how m.size is 4 because the new 'i' overrides the previous 'i' just wanna nkow how i=3,came=1 is printed.

Comment: @TruePS The print function is handled by HashMap itself, if that's your question

Comment: @TruePS You said *then it gets 'a'* -- be careful here, `a` is just the variable name. It is in fact holding one of the values of you array (a different one at each loop turn.

Comment: @jeoffrey No that's not my question i know that came,left,saw and i are keys and i know that freq is their values but frequency is not intialized so how it is printing 1 or 3

Comment: @TruePS when the `put` puts 1 in the map, it does initialize that value. If ever you call `get` later on, you get that 1 for `freq`. I'll elaborate my answer if you want.

Comment: @Joffrey I got the answer man thanks for your valuable time.P.S. When I posted that question I was looking that somebody would tell me like that when 'i' is get then this happens,when 'came' is  get then this happens<I just wanted to know each and every iteration of for-each loop.

Comment: @TruePS I was about to do so ^^ I'm glad you got it ;)

Comment: @Joffrey Wow you really increased my knowledge I just found out that meaning of ^^ is blissful

Answer (score 2):

This loop,

```
for (String a : argss) {
  Integer freq = m.get(a); 
  m.put(a, (freq == null) ? 1 : freq + 1);
}
```

Starts with a null in freq, but the put then turns null into 1with the ternary expression which acts like an if -

```
// m.put(a, (freq == null) ? 1 : freq + 1);
if (freq == null) {
  m.put(a, 1);
} else {
  m.put(a, freq + 1);
}
```

**EDIT**

From the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29) (emphasis mine) - 
Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped, **or null** if this map contains no mapping for the key.

`null` is the concept "not a value". If you wanted to guard against it, you could have tested if the map contains a value with a given key. That method is [boolean containsKey(Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsKey%28java.lang.Object%29).

Comment: How it is distinguishing between distinct and non-distinct words.

Comment: Edited to try and clarify that for you.

Answer (score 1):

In your for-loop you can test beforehand, if the element is in the map and if not, you put it with frequency 0 into it.

```
for (String a : argss) {
    if(m.get(a) == null) {
        m.put(a,0);
    }
    Integer freq = m.get(a);
    m.put(a, freq + 1);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments but I just want to know the working of above program.

Answer (score 1):

By Line 
 m.get(a); You are getting value.For the first case ,it is null.

Now through Line 
  m.put(a, (freq == null) ? 1 : freq + 1);

You are putting value a (from string array) and if freq== null you are adding 1 in value.
if it is not null you are incrementing freq value by 1.

Comment: How this program is distinguishing between distinct and non-distinct words.

Comment: In Map when we insert the same key again it overrides the previous one..So that is why it is printing only single value for "i",not printing it 3 times.

Comment: I understood that m.size is 4 but how i=3,came=1 etc is printing.

Comment: m.get("came") will give null.                                   m.put(a, (freq == null) ? 1 : freq + 1); 
so if null it will increment by 1.

now for i ;
at start m.get("i") = null and it will increment by 1 so m.put("i",1)

now m.get("i") will give 1 . now m.put("i",2) :2 because incrementing 1 by 1 and so on.